# jQuery - Make users fill out form before video plays

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, video, onclick

I need to make it so that when a user clicks the embedded youtube video to play the video, a form appears where they have to submit valid info in order for the video to continue playing.

Where could I get a good starting point on this?

I have a link that I can click that pops up a form but I don't know how to connect that to an iframe (cant use onclick with an iframe) and then make it required that they submit valid info before the video plays.

Comment: place an element over the iFrame, pop up the form when clicking that element, and remove the element and play the video underneath when the form is submitted.

Comment: A good starting point is showing us what your code looks like so far :)